# Custom contextMenu or QuickAction dialog possible in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Good day, am pretty new to Windows Phone development. i am in process of prototyping an app for the windows phone so i need to know what i can/can't do or how close i can get to that kind of functionality. My question is, is there a way you can have a custom QuickAction or ContextMenu dialog when a button is pressed, in windows phone, just like you have in android.

[image: quickactionbar]

anything like this possible or how best can i get a popup with images? Please any link to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radial Menu from Syncfusion Windows Phone toolkit, can serve as a quick context menu. It displays a hierarchical menu in a circular layout optimized for touch devices.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/controls

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to look into is using the [`Windows Phone Toolkit`'s](http://phone.codeplex.com/) `ContextMenu` class.

This will allow you to implement a Context Menu like: [image: Context Menu example]

Have a read of http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-contextmenu-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api which should get you going!